# Any modern camera that has a visual aperture indicator?

Tags: aperture, camera, display

[image]

On the back of the Nikon D3200 seen in the picture we can see a graphical representation of the selected aperture. Are any modern cameras able to show that in some mode?

Comment: Any digital camera would be considered "modern" by the vast majority of photographers who have practiced the craft over the past two centuries or so. Are you asking what *current* models include the same thing as the D3200? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: ”Modern cameras" is a moving target subject to changing markets.  What's preventing you from looking at screenshots in reviews of cameras you're interested in?

Comment: @Michael C yes current is maybe better, I am referring to cameras still availible from their parent copmany

Comment: @xiota I considered adding an i 2020 but I have been told earlier that a moving target is preferable on this site

Comment: @xiota, I tried too find pictures online but my googling failed me

Comment: I'm curious what the underlying goal is of having such a visual indicator. Why are you looking for this UI element?

Comment: What photographic problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: I was trying to help a friend shop for a new camera, they mentioned that they realy liked it as they less often forgot to use the right aparture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All recent Nikon entry level DSLR cameras, (including the most recent D3500 and D5600) have the option to display the aperture being used as a graphic display. Other Nikon cameras may also have this option.

Here is page 208 of the D3500 manual which shows you how to choose this option.
[image]

Canon entry level cameras have something similar called “Guided Mode”, but it doesn’t include an aperture graphic like Nikon.
[image]

Comment: I can add to this that using search terms from this the d5600 also have this.